# Can't get a valid ListView.SelectedIndex

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

So I'm having trouble getting back a correct SelectedIndex in a click event. No matter what item I select, I always get back -1

Here is my event :

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var index = CitiesDisplay.SelectedIndex;
    if(CitiesDisplay.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    { 
        vm.Cities.Remove(vm.Cities[index]);
    }
}
```

And here is my ListView :

```
<ListView Name="CitiesDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Holding="ListViewItem_Holding">
                <!-- Begin Flyout menu -->
                <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Navigate To" Click="NavigateTo_Click"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                <!-- End Flyout Menu -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Name="CityName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="MaxTemp" Text="{Binding max}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="MinTemp" Text="{Binding min}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="CurrentTemp" Text="{Binding temp}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Image Name="Logo" Width="50" Height="50" Source="{Binding icon}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I really don't understand why I can't get my SelectedIndex because I did the same thing in a previous project and it worked flawlessly.

I have also tried manipulating SelectedItems to no avail.

Some additional details : I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 App (winrt) using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Comment: Out of curosity if you debug into your CitiesDisplay object does it have anything in the collection?

Comment: @CathalMF When debugging into CitiesDisplay, I do indeed have the Items collection, which does contain my items (and they are displayed anyway).

Comment: Are you binding your list view in the code with something like CitiesDisplay.ItemsSource = MyItems; Maybe when you change the display the item source is resetting everything.

Comment: Yes I am binding it like this : CitiesDisplay.DataContext = vm.Cities (where vm is my ViewModel)

Comment: Where are you setting your DataContext?

Comment: I am currently setting it in my `private async void MainPivot_LoadingPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)` , when the corresponding pivot is loaded. I have however tried to load it in the MainPage() to no avail.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the LoadingPivotItem method. When is it being called? It could be resetting your DataContext when you dont want it to.

Comment: I have just done that but when deploying and clicking on the flyout, the breakpoint never gets triggered so it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your `SelectedIndex` will always remain as -1 as neither `ItemClick` nor `SelectionChanged` events would trigger due to the design constraint of click event being consumed by your `ItemTemplate` Stackpanel's `Holding` event.
To fix this you would

1. Require to traverse your `VisualTree` till the parent
   ItemTemplate
2. Typecast its content to your Binding model and try to get the value.

Your XAML would remain same your code behind would change to

```
private DependencyObject GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(DependencyObject startObject, Type type)
        {              
            DependencyObject parent = startObject;
            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (type.IsInstanceOfType(parent))
                    break;
                else
                    parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
            }
            return parent;
        }


        private void Delete_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = GetDependencyObjectFromVisualTree(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject, typeof(ListViewItem)) as ListViewItem;      
//here you can use it to traverse your vm.Cities list to update it or do anything.
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(((YourModel)selectedItem.Content).Cities);
        }
```